# Getting highchrts series name incorrect only in my tests

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have bar chart which drill down to several other charts by clicking on different series. I captured the clicked series name to show the respective chart in drill downs. It absolutely worked as expected when i check manually on my UI. I am using

```
this.series.name // to get the series 
this.name // to get the point name
```

But i have test cases written for verifying the data of this charts with drill downs and here all my tests were failing on because not getting the clicked series name correctly which so weird for me.

```
this.series.name // to get the series 
this.name // to get the point name
```

These results same output as point name and causes my tests to fail.

```
    plotOptions : {
                series : {
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function() {
                                $("#getid").val(this.name);
                                $("#getseriesname").val(this.series.name);
                                $("#getsome").val($("#given").val());
                                console.log("()()((* " + this.series.name + " *** " + this.name); // results (this.series.name==this.name) only in tests verifying                                                                  
                                chartDrilldown('someotherreport', {
                                    name: 'gettype',
                                    value: $("#getval").val(),
                                });
                            }                           
                        }                       
                    }                   
                }
             },
```

I do not understand why this is failing to get the series name in tests. Can any one point me the mistake.

Comment: What's the `chartDrilldown` function?

Comment: I do not suspect that method behavior and basically this drill down to specific name mentioned in the first argument.

Comment: A little bit unclear, so you mean that this.series.name returns incorrect names? Could you replicate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net ?